# Using JDOQL results in Scala

Tags: scala, jdo, scala-collections

I'm trying to use a JDO with Google App Engine and Scala.  The api for the execute returns `Object` (but it's really a java collection) and I want to get it into a scala list to iterate over it.

My code looks like this so far:

```
val pm = PMF.factory.getPersistenceManager
val query = "select from User " 
val gamelist:List[User] = List(pm.newQuery(query).execute.toArray:_ *)
```

The compile error at this point is toArray is not a member of Object.  What is the best way to do the above?  I tried to use `.asInstanceOf[java.util.Collection[User]]`, but it was a failed attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use scala.collection.jcl.Conversions:

```
import scala.collection.jcl.Conversions._
...
// this gets you a List[User]
val gameList = pm.newQuery(query).execute.asInstanceOf[java.util.List[User]].toList
...
// or you can just iterate through the return value without converting it to List
pm.newQuery(query).execute.asInstanceOf[java.util.List[User]] foreach (println(_))
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the Java collection is not a scala collection. Youy need the implicit conversions in the `jcl` package:

```
import collections.jcl.Conversions._
import java.util.{Collection => JCollection}

val pm = PMF.factory.getPersistenceManager
val query = "select from User " 

val users = pm.newQuery(query).execute.asInstanceOf[JCollection[User]]
val gamelist:List[User] = List(users.toArray: _*) //implicit conversion here
```